# Dataframe groupby date and other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that has three columns, date (Y-M-D), shop_id and revenue. I would like to group the table by month, shop_id and rank the revenue from the highest value to the lowest one. The table has two million rows covers three years record. You can view the table from the links I attached. I tried something like this:

```
 monthSales.groupby((monthSales['date'].dt.strftime('%B'),monthSales['shop_id'])) 

 please see this link: "paste.ofcode.org/GvTNdqtWWGTZR5ysJEKnVQ" to 
 copy the toy table
```

How should I do it? Thanks for your help!

Data in copyable format:

```
    date    shop_id revenue
0   2013-01-02  59  22131846.0
1   2013-01-23  24  22131846.0
2   2013-01-20  27  22131846.0
3   2013-01-02  25  22131846.0
4   2013-01-03  25  22131846.0
5   2013-01-20  25  22131846.0
6   2013-01-23  25  22131846.0
7   2013-01-26  25  22131846.0
8   2013-01-27  6   22131846.0
9   2013-01-10  15  22131846.0
10  2013-01-10  7   22131846.0
11  2013-01-05  31  22131846.0
12  2013-01-02  54  22131846.0
13  2013-01-14  42  22131846.0
14  2013-01-26  38  22131846.0
15  2013-01-20  37  22131846.0
16  2013-01-02  46  22131846.0
17  2013-01-08  44  22131846.0
18  2013-02-05  51  14555178.0
19  2013-02-12  54  22131846.0
20  2013-02-12  16  22131846.0
21  2013-02-22  1   14555178.0
22  2013-02-10  0   14555178.0
23  2013-02-05  0   14555178.0
24  2013-03-21  28  22131846.0
```

Comment: Do not post images! We cannot copy the data to duplicate...

Comment: @SergeBallesta, please see the link I attached. Stackoverflow does not allow me to paste the table code. Thanks!

Comment: I have done it for you. You should use the [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60586883/revisions) link to see how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first build a month column. If the date column has a datetime dtype, you can substract the day number and add 1 to get first month of day. If it has a string type, you can slice the 7 first characters.

Once this is done you first group by that month column and apply a sort_values, ascending=False to each part.

Pandas code could be (datetime example):

```
df.assign(month=df.date + pd.to_timedelta(1 - df.date.dt.day, 'D')).groupby(
    ['month']).apply(lambda x: x.groupby(['shop_id']).sum().sort_values(
            'revenue', ascending=False))
```

giving:

```
                        revenue
month      shop_id             
2013-01-01 25       110659230.0
           6         22131846.0
           7         22131846.0
           15        22131846.0
           24        22131846.0
           27        22131846.0
           31        22131846.0
           37        22131846.0
           38        22131846.0
           42        22131846.0
           44        22131846.0
           46        22131846.0
           54        22131846.0
           59        22131846.0
2013-02-01 0         29110356.0
           16        22131846.0
           54        22131846.0
           1         14555178.0
           51        14555178.0
2013-03-01 28        22131846.0
```

Answer (score 1):

`.groupby` takes a column or list of columns to group on, and expects a function to be applied at the end.

The columns should be passed to `.groupby` as the headers, not the columns themselves: just the names as strings. Because `.groupby` is called on a dataframe, Pandas can work out that you meant the columns.

`df.groupby(by=['date', 'shop_id'])`

Once you've passed in the columns correctly, you need to add the function on the end to actually calculate anything. In your case, you want the `sum` function.

`df.groupby(by=['date', 'shop_id']).sum()`

You can then sort the dataframe using `.sort_values` as normal.

You'll also need to convert your `date` column into actual dates using `pd.to_datetime` and extract the month (probably to another column) before you group everything, otherwise the sorting won't do what you want.

---

I think this code does what you want:

```
monthSales.loc[:, "date"] = pd.to_datetime(monthSales["date"])
monthSales["month"] = monthSales["date"].dt.strftime('%m')
monthSales.groupby(["month", "shop_id"]).sum().sort_values('month')
```

If you want to preserve the year as well (and not fiddle about with multi-indexes):

```
monthSales.loc[:, "date"] = pd.to_datetime(monthSales["date"])
monthSales["month"] = monthSales["date"].dt.strftime('%m')
monthSales["year"] = monthSales["date"].dt.strftime('%Y')
monthSales.groupby(["year", "month", "shop_id"]).sum().sort_values('month')
```

And if you do want to mess around with multindexes:

```
monthSales.loc[:, "date"] = pd.to_datetime(monthSales["date"])
monthSales.set_index('date', inplace=True)
monthSales.groupby([monthSales.index.year.values,
                    monthSales.index.month.values, "shop_id"]).sum()
```

Comment: @Pertitract, I will run the test. But I tried many times, the row 3-7 (shop_id 25) just does not combine together. Will let you know soon.

Comment: @Pertitract, It was the same result as the table I pasted. BTW, when it was grouped by date, it did not show in month

Comment: @Petriact, Thanks for your help! This time, I found the year was disappeared:) I mean if I run the sql code, I would like something like groupby ("month", "shop_id").order by "Revenue" Desc.. something like that

Comment: @almo I've re-edited with two more options, both of which preserve the year. See if either of those does what you want.

Comment: @Petriact, thanks. I think your solution works fine but I like more Serge's solution. Thanks  a lot